# 24V ceramic heater to work on 12V?

Tags: power-supply

I have a 40W ceramic heater, which needs to work with 24V but I only have a 12V power supply.

Will the heater work with 12V?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it'll only use a quarter of the power (10 watts) and put out a quarter of the heat.

Per Ohm's law, V=IR, with half the voltage, I'll draw half the current. Per P=IV, with half voltage and half current, it'll consume one quarter power.

Note that this is approximate since, as @Brian Drummond pointed out, the resistance of the heater may be lower when cooler. This will increase the power at lower voltage, but only slightly.

Comment: It may be slightly more powerful than 10W as its heating element won't reach the same temperature, thus working at a slightly lower resistance, consuming slightly more than half the current, but this is probably close enough.

Comment: @Brian Drummond: If it's nichrome wire, its resistance doesn't change significantly with temperature. That's one of the reasons nichrome is used in heaters.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff - A ceramic heater doesn't use nichrome wire, does it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_element#Ceramic_heating_elements

Comment: That article is one of the most confused on Wikipedia (if you read all of it--never mind the tags), so who knows... Around my back of the woods, often enough the nichrome wire is incorporated in a factory-made sealed "ceramic" disc element (actually something made of [aluminium borosilicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borosilicate_glass#Other), IIRC) and you can't see any wire except two short leads. I wouldn't bet most people can tell this apart from a PTC ceramic by just looking... including the OP. And, yeah I did tear one apart so I'm sure mine had nichrome wire inside. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use or [build](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGp82xhybs4) a DC-DC boost converter to double the voltage for your heater. David Jones [explains it in details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-V_p1GBH4pk) on his video blog.

Comment: A 40W boost converter is probably out of the realm of someone asking this question.

Comment: I never make assumptions of this kind. If the OP feels confident enough at least he hast the information. What he does [or not] with it is up to him.